# PHP - cropping image

Tags: php, imagick

I have got this image :

[image]

And i need to crop the top and bottom, so i will get this :

[image]

I was searching for a while, but did not find a solution, it needs to be done in PHP.

Comment: The portions at the top and bottom you wish to remove - are they consistently sized?

Comment: What have you tried so far that hasn't worked? You should at least attempt to solve the problem first.

Comment: I understand, i already tried few things, but i found way to crop top, not the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use imagecrop() method to crop any image as follows:

```
$filename = 'test.JPG';
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename );
    $x_size = getimagesize($filename)[0];
    $y_size = getimagesize($filename)[1];
    $crop_measure = min($x_size, $y_size);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    $crop_array = array('x' =>0 , 'y' => 0, 'width' => $crop_measure, 'height'=> $crop_measure);
    $thumb_image = imagecrop($image, $crop_array);
```